# Can't disable Custom Timer Job

Tags: timer-jobs

I has created a CustomTimerJob to update my list but i can't disable this timerjob because the title is disable, I can't click or do anything. I can't not find it in job definition but it automatically run every minute. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is attached to a list you will want to include that as so:

```
Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like "*<List_JOB_NAME>*" } |ft id,name
```

Not just the Job Name, I find the post is not explicit enough.

Comment: Posted incorrectly like"*<List_JOB_NAME>*"}

Answer (score 0):

You can retract the solution from Visual Studio or run command:

MOSS 2007 [[CREDITS]](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminlegacy/thread/6c54d287-a262-4132-8c2d-34752924f1bf): Stsadm

> If you would like to delete Sharepoint Timer Job Definitions follow
>   these steps
>   - In Central Administration Home Page click Operations tab
>   - Then click Timer Job Definitions link
>   - In this page go to the job whick you want to delete
>   - While pointing your mouse over this job note down the GUID shown in status bar
>   - Then go stsadm and run this command
>   `stsadm.exe -o deleteconfigurationobject -id`

SharePoint 2010: Powershell

```
#Searching listing and find timer job to delete.We need an id.
Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like "*<your search criteria>*" } |ft id,name

#Set job to a variable
$job = Get-SPTimerJob -id <GUID>

#And delete it.
$job.Delete()
```

**NOTE: Do not remove without making sure the $job you got is what you need to delete!**

Comment: I can't find job id, job title is disable. I deleted the old project, so can't find the guid ID

Comment: Run `Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.name -like "*<your search criteria>*" } |ft id,name` to get GUID for Timer Job